# Two base sub-objects vs. ambiguity

Tags: c++, inheritance

The following code comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4118705/2725810) post:

```
struct Base
{
    Base( int ) {}
    void foo() const {}
};

struct Intermediate: Base
{
    Intermediate( int x )
        : Base( x )
    {}
};

struct ResolvableBase: Base
{
    ResolvableBase( int x ): Base( x ) {}
};

struct Derived: Intermediate, ResolvableBase
{
    Derived( int x )
        : Intermediate( x )
        , ResolvableBase( x )
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived o( 667 );
    o.ResolvableBase::foo();    // OK.
}
```

The author of this code seems to claim that `o` has two sub-objects of `Base`. Why is this the case of two sub-objects and not the case of ambiguity (in which case `gcc` would have warned about inaccessible base class)? Also, if there are two sub-objects, then which sub-objects's `foo` gets called in `main`?

Comment: If `Derived` was declared as `struct Derived: Base, ResolvableBase` you'd get ambiguity

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - that's not ambiguous. Using an unqualified name to access a member of `Base` would be ambiguous, just as in the code in the question, with the added complication that there's no way to disambiguate the name to refer to a member of the direct `Base`. But `ResolvableBase::name` works here, just as it does in the original.

Comment: @PeteBecker using a qualified name to access members of a direct base class would be ambiguous, and that's the ambiguity I'm referring to, and which OP expects to see (a warning from gcc)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this the case of two sub-objects and not the case of ambiguity

Because there is two distinct subobjects we can address separately if we want.

> if there are two sub-objects, then which sub-objects's foo gets called in main?

One belonging to `ResolvableBase`, as you explicitely requested that one:

```
o.ResolvableBase::foo();    // OK.
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ← Here
```