# Object with its own thread and thread from inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, encapsulation

I have two objects

```
class Protocol : public UDPServer, private Thread { void loop(); ... };
class UDPServer : private Thread { void loop(); ... };
```

where Thread is a class which will call the object's loop-method in its own thread and where UDPServer will call a notify()-function in Protocol whenever it receives a new message.

Each of the two objects should run its own loop() during runtime (hence the two Thread-inheritances). According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118412/inaccessible-direct-base-caused-by-multiple-inheritance), this is not possible the way I wrote it.

I now wonder if I have to copy and rename the Thread-class to solve this problem or whether there's another workaround? I could probably solve this with two separate objects and circular inheritance but this would make the code somewhat more complex ...

Comment: I don't know how your `Thread` class actually works, but does it require inheritance strictly? Then a better approach might be using plain `std::thread` member variables in the base and the derived class.

Comment: Off topic: [Take a look at select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html). It may do what you need to do without threads.

Comment: Yes, it does. I never used `std::thread` before since the Thread-class was always here. I'm currently looking into that - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user4581301 Two problems here: a) `UDPServer` is used at quite a few places throughout the code, so I can't really change the code there a lot. b) Some of those places (including `Protocol`) do not watch a file descriptor, but have reoccurring tasks (i.e. they wait for some time and then do something). I guess I can't use `select` here, can I?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There's nothing that's obviously wrong here and you haven't mentioned any errors. Yes, you can't get at members of `UDPServer`'s direct base, but nothing in the text here suggests that this is an issue.

Comment: Incidentally, I think that the text in the question muddles "object" and "class".

Comment: You could if you wrapped `select` in `UDPServer`, but it's a pretty radical change from what you currently have. Based on what you ahve described, you should be able to uncouple `Protocol` from `UDPServer`. Create a new class `UDPClient` or some such that contains pure virtual method `notify`. `Protocol` implements `UDPClient`. `UDPServer` is provided a pointer to a `UDPClient`, in this case a `Protocol`, and calls the `notify` function on data arrival. Now nobody knows nothin' besides the common `UDPClient` interface and you don't have the problem with `Thread`.

Comment: @PeteBecker hm, yeah, I mixed that up, sorry. Mainly talking about classes here, not so much about objects. Point is that I have two classes, one inheriting the other and both of them should run in different threads while thread-functionality comes from the `Thread`-class.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, that's basically what I meant with "I could probably solve this with two separate objects" but I was hoping there would be another solution which would require me to pass pointers around.

Comment: @user4581301 Oh, and I just looked it up: `UDPServer` indeed uses `select`. But I don't see how that could help me here since I still have to poll the data at some point?

Comment: You can rig `select` to tell you when the data arrives. A typical use is to have a thread looping around a `select` statement, possibly for all running `UDPServers`. When data arrives, `select` returns, you run through which sockets received data and call the appropriate `Protocol` object to handle them. You wind up with one `UDPSserver` that handles multiple `Protocol`s, almost halving the number of threads you have running.

Comment: Anyway, you are building yourself into a bit of nastiness where `Protocol` needs to know about `UDPServer` since it inherits it, and `UDPServer` needs to know `Protocol` so `UDPServer` can call `Protocol::notify`. That sort of circular referencing is extremely hard to get right. Much better to have `Protocol` contain a `UDPServer` and have `UDPServer` interact with an abstraction of `Protocol`. Since `Protocol` contains `UDPServer` you don't have to worry about `UDPServer`'s pointer to `Protocol` being invalidated, because `UDPServer` will always go out of scope first.

Comment: @user4581301 "thread looping around a `select`" well, exactly that was my problem; I wasn't able to run two threads (since my `Protocol` also required one) with the given Thread-class. I now implemented what you proposed in the last comment as it seems to be the easiest solution here. Thanks! :-)