# C++ Template Inheritance Issues (Warnings and Errors)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to mimic the .Net implementation of a generic List in C++.

I've fleshed out the various `interfaces` as purely virtual abstract classes as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class ICollection {

public:
    virtual void Add(T item) = 0;
    virtual void Clear(void) = 0;
    virtual bool Contains(T item) = 0;
    virtual void Remove(T item) = 0;

    virtual int32_t Count(void) const = 0;

};

template <typename T>
class IList : public ICollection<T> {

public:
    virtual T Item(int32_t index) = 0;
    virtual int32_t IndexOf(T item) = 0;
    virtual void Insert(int32_t index, T item) = 0;
    virtual void RemoveAt(int32_t index) = 0;

};
```

Now when I attempt to implement my main `List` class as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class List : public IList<T>, public ICollection<T> {

public:
    List(void);
    List(int32_ capacity);

    // ICollection<T>
    void Add(T item);
    // other functions from ICollection

    // IList<T>
    T Item(int32_t index);
    // other functions from IList

    void AddRange(IList<T> items);

private:
    typedef vector<T> ListType;

    ListType *m_pList;
};


template <typename T>
List<T>::List(void) {
    m_pList = new ListType();
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::Insert(uint32_t index, T item) {
    // Insert an entry into the list at the specified offset
    m_list->insert(index, item);
}

// Implementation of other functions here...
```

As soon as I try to use the `List<T>` class as follows:

```
List<int32_t> myList;
```

A warning occurs saying:

```
In instantiation of 'class List<long int>':
    required from here
warning: direct base 'ICollection<long int>' inaccessible in 'List<long int>' due to ambiguity [enabled by default]

class List : public IList<T>, public ICollection<T> {
       ^
```

Followed by the following error:

```
In instantiation of 'void List<T>::Insert(uint32_t, T) [with T = long int; uint32_t = long unsigned int]':
    required from here
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<long int, std::allocator<long int> >::insert(uint32_t&, long int&)'

m_list->insert(index, item);
^

note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const value_type&) [with _Tp = long int; _Alloc = std::allocator<long int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long int*, std::vector<long int, std::allocator<long int> > >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = long int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = long int]

 vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
 ^

 note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'uint32_t {aka long unsigned int}' to 'std::vector<long int, std::allocator<long int> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long int*, std::vector<long int, std::allocator<long int> > >}'
```

If I modify the declaration of the `List<T>` class so as to remove the `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` abstract classes, no errors are generated.

I'm guessing that the way in which I'm using the templated base classes is not correct in this instance.

Comment: You have multiple problems: 1) Objects in C++ do not work like .NET or Java objects, they are fundamentally different 2) Multiple inheritance. For more information, get a good C++ book. These are fundamental concepts that cannot be fully explained in a brief stackoverflow.com answer. Trying to learn C++ by relying on your knowledge of .NET is a recipe for endless failure and confusion because, as I said, C++ objects work completely differently. Did you know, for example, that all your methods must take a `const` reference as a parameter, and not a value? See your C++ book for the reason why.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 1) I fully understand this. 2) I don't need a good book and I'm not trying to "learn C++" but I am trying to understand why the templating system or my implementation of, in this instance is creating errors due to multiple inheritance. Not relying on any knowledge of .Net - in fact, I've not touched it for a good while.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118412/inaccessible-direct-base-caused-by-multiple-inheritance

Comment: For starters, this has nothing to do with templates. The same exact compilation errors will occur with the same class structure and without templates anywhere in the picture. And if you're "trying to understand" something about C++, whether it's templates or a anything else, a good C++ book is a requirement. C++ Templates are not classes, and classes are not templates (unlike .NET or Java, which have absolutely nothing like C++ templates, even if they have something that looks very similar to it), and the errors are due to class inheritance, and not with anything related to templates.

Comment: [OT] You would avoid problem by using `vector` directly instead of pointer on `vector` (Rule of 0/3/5).

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not directly related to templates.

```
class A {
    public void f() {}
};

class B : public A {};

class C : public A, public B {};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.f(); // Error: ambiguous base class!
}
```

When you inherit a class, the derived class contains an object for the base class, called a base class subobject.  So in my example, every `B` contains an `A`.  And every `C` contains an `A` and a `B`.  The problem is, when I try to call `f` as a member of `C`, the compiler needs to find the `A` subobject to call it on.  But there are two subobjects with that type!  One is directly inherited by `C`, and the other is inside the inherited `B` subobject.  So the compiler can't figure out what I mean.

The solution in this case is to just not inherit a class twice.  In my example, `C` doesn't need to directly inherit `A`, since inheriting `B` will provide it with an indirect `A` subobject and access to all its members.

In your case, `List<T>` doesn't need to inherit `ICollection<T>` directly.  It's enough to just derive from `IList<T>`.

(In other cases, it can be useful to use "virtual inheritance", which tells the compiler "only create one base class subobject for this type, even if I indirectly inherit it more than once in some derived class". But that might be overkill for your code as it stands.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Understand your point about not needing to inherit from `ICollection<T>`, I was just unsure as to the visibility of the `ICollection<T>` functions from within the `List<T>` class but given that its marked as `public`, it was kinda obvious.