# C++: multiple inheritance using virtual

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

**Still  learning basics of C++**

I have a very simple query regarding the virtual keyword in multiple inheritance.
I have the following code:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

//1. class C : public A, public B {};
//2. class C : virtual public A, public B {};
//3. class C : public A, virtual public B {};
//4. class C : virtual public A, virtual public B {};

int main() {
    C f;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I know (by actually trying this code out), that 1 and 3, both cases where we do not use virtual keyword while inheriting  class A work.

I understand it is the Diamond Problem of multiple inheritance, and the compiler error goes away when I inherit class A as virtual in class B:

```
class B: virtual public A
```

But I wanted to experiment with the code and removed it.

My question is, Why does creation of an object of class C fail when we inherit class A using virtual?

---

> Note: I could not find a good article to explain **in depth** what this virtual keyword means and how the compiler reads it and **what does the compiler do after reading the Virtual Keyword**.

EDIT:

1. This is an experiment that I am doing, so no practical use (to me personally).
2. When do this:

> ```
> class A {};
> class B : public A {};
> class C : virtual public A, virtual public B {};
>
> int main() {
>     C f;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Compiler throws error: error C2584: 'C': direct base 'A' is inaccessible; already a base of 'B'

3. even when I don't use virtual, compiler still gives the error msg as a "Warning"

Comment: What is the reason `C` should inherit from both `A` and `B`? If it inherits from `B` only it *also* inherits from `A`, since `B` already inherits from `A`. Indirect inheritance is still inheritance.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please show any error messages.

Comment: I have trouble believing you cannot find resources on virtual inheritance -- it has been in the language for 20 years already.

Comment: "This works, that fails" is not a useful problem statement. What fails? what error do you get?

Comment: @Quentin - It's *virtually* everywhere :P

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) seems pretty well-documented  [to me](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond), maybe you could say specifically what you don't understand?

Comment: @StoryTeller ***sigh***.

Comment: @Quentin - Oh come on, terrible puns are what SO comments exist for :)

Comment: @StoryTeller *diamonds* are forever, but fortunately these comments aren't -- no risk of anyone *inheriting* that.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118412/inaccessible-direct-base-caused-by-multiple-inheritance

Comment: @LeNgocThuong- I Saw that, and got confused when I read, "If you try to directly convert to A, it will have two possibilities." My understanding is if I made A virtual, I will only have 1 copy of it's members

Comment: @Harshad - The problem here is that B has a non-virtual base class A, so you will get more like one-and-a-half base class. Can't see any use case for that. Only reminds me of *"Doctor, Doctor, it hurts when I do this"*

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118412/inaccessible-direct-base-caused-by-multiple-inheritance