# c++ Access to base class members with "diamond" inheritance syntax

Tags: c++

Suppose, I want to make a class like below and don't use virtual inheritance.
What is the syntax of accessing "upper" class's members from "lower" instance?
Had figures some ways for left and righ, but not sure which is "canonically" correct. And how to access member lower---upper way?

```
/*       upper
        /  |  \
     left  |  right
        \  |  /
         lower
*/

class upper {
public:
int base;};

class left : public upper  {};

class right : public upper {};

class lower : public right, public left, public upper {};

int main(){

lower a;

// a.base=1;        // error: request for member 'base' is ambiguous
// a.upper::left::lower::base=1;    // error: 'upper::left' has not been declared
// a.lower::left::upper::base=2;    // error: 'upper' is an ambiguous base of 'lower'
// a.left::upper::base=1;           // error: 'upper' is an ambiguous base of 'lower'

// a.lower::upper::base=1;  // error: 'upper' is an ambiguous base of 'lower'
// a.upper::lower::base=1   // error: 'upper::lower' has not been declared

a.lower::left::base=1;  // works
a.right::base=1;        // works

return 0;}
```

Thanks.

P.S. I have read about dangers of using it. :)

Comment: You said you have read about the danger, I would avoid inheritance in such a case anyway. Instead of inheritance, you can always use aggregation. So instead of deriving the classes "left", "right" and "lower" from "upper", you could just introduce members like "upper m_left", "upper m_right".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118412/inaccessible-direct-base-caused-by-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a diamond scheme, this is a "cursed diamond". Inheritance diamond doesn't have direct line from base class to most derived class.  You can't access `upper` in any way  due to ambiguous inheritance. And you already got two instances of upper inside of two "flanking" classes.

Some may expect that

```
a.lower::upper::base = 1;
```

should work. It should not. `lower` as a namespace contains two `upper`s from `left` and `right` and one from its own declaration. While you can specify namespace for the `upper` inside of `left` and `right`, you can't do that for the direct "third wheel" in that parenthood. It's just same as if you tried to do this:

```
/*       upper
        /     \
     left     right
        \     /
         lower
*/

a.upper::base = 1;
```

In this case you may make it work, but this kind of approach to architecture is questionable. As it raises the question if you actually are in dire need of the component-entity pattern.

```
/*       upper
        /  |  \
   left center right
        \  |  /
         lower
*/
```

In other words: while having more than two parents in relationship for sake of grandparent  being able to reach its grandchild is interesting, on practice bacteria with their plasmids have found a better way.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought there must be a way, I mean the variable is actually stored, how come it is not possible to access it?

Comment: @Timofeus blind side of existing syntax rules. Actually, compilers warn about this. E.g. g++ generates "direct base 'upper' is inaccessible due to ambiguity" warning. It's just if you write function with argument name that masks name of global variable. Name masking doesn't require diagnostics or errors.