# C++ primer 5th ed. Virtual inheritance and ctor-init

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

On C++ primer 5th Ed. Chapter 18. Multiple and virtual inheritance, I have this question:

> Exercise 18.30: Define a default constructor, a copy constructor, and a constructor that has an int parameter in Base. Define the same three constructors in each derived class. Each constructor should use its argument to initialize its Base part.

I've tried to solve it this way so here is my inheritance hierarchy:

```
struct Class {
    Class(){cout << "Class()\n";}
    ~Class(){cout << "~Class()\n";}
};

struct Base : Class {
    Base(){cout << "Base()\n";}
    Base(int){cout << "Base(int)\n";}
    Base(Base const&){cout << "Base(Base const&)\n";}

    ~Base(){cout << "~Base()\n";}
};

struct D1 : virtual public Base {
    D1(){cout << "D1()\n";}
    D1(int x) : Base(x){
        cout << "D1(int)\n";
    }
    D1(D1 const& rhs) : Base(rhs){
        cout << "D1(D1 const&)\n";
    }

    ~D1(){cout << "~D1()\n";}
};

struct D2 : virtual public Base {
    D2(){cout << "D2()\n";}
    D2(int x) : Base(x){
        cout << "D2(int)\n";
    }
    D2(D2 const& rhs) : Base(rhs){
        cout << "D2(D2 const&)\n";
    }
    ~D2(){cout << "~D2()\n";}
};

struct MI : public D1, public D2 {
    MI(){cout << "MI()\n";}
    MI(int x) : Base(x), D1(x), D2(x){
        cout << "MI(int)\n";
    }
    MI(MI const& rhs) : Base(rhs), D1(rhs), D2(rhs){
        cout << "MI(MI const&)\n";
    }

    ~MI(){cout << "~MI()\n";}
};

struct Final : public MI, public Class {
    Final(){cout << "Final()\n";}
    Final(int x) : MI(x){
        cout << "Final(int)\n";
    }
    Final(Final const& rhs) : MI(rhs), Class(rhs){
        cout << "Final(Final const&)\n";
    }

    ~Final(){cout << "~Final()\n";}
};
```

Now if I compile the program I get the error:

```
 error: ‘Class’ is an ambiguous base of ‘Final’
```

So the problem is in the class `Final`'s copy-constructor initialization-list so how could I initialize the subpart of `Class` in the Copy-constructor.

- The `Final(int)` doesn't complain because I've let the default ctor of `Class()` run:

  ```
    Final(int x) : MI(x) // Class default ctor is executed.
  ```

So help me to get around this problem. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have that book in front of me but I'm going to guess that you misunderstood some part of the excersize that you did not include in your description (such as what, precisely, does "each derived class" means). Otherwise, based on the shown code, the book is asking you to implement a crazy class hierarchy. Something I wouldn't expect a reputable book to promote.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I've only implemented the asked constructors and copied&pasted the exercise.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Does this because `Base` is a virtual base class thus must be initialized by the most derived class thus it must look like: `Final(Final const& rhs) : Base(rhs), MI(rhs){
            cout << "Final(Final const&)\n";
        }`
Now this works fine?!

Comment: I don't understand the reason for `struct Final : public MI, public Class`.  `struct Final -> struct MI -> struct D1 -> struct Base -> struct Class` inheritance chain is already there, so then what's the point of writing that piece of `public Class`. Remove that.

Comment: Please pretend that you are a complete stranger who doesn't know anything, who does not have this book, and who reads the description of the excersize, that you quoted above. Only those three sentences and absolutely nothing else, whatsoever. That's all that you, a complete stranger knows. Now, can you answer the following question: do you have any idea, any idea at all, what "each derived class" means in the description of the "copied&pasted the excersize"?

Answer (score 1):

This is the case of the *inaccessible-base* class. The `Final` class already has an inheritance chain as:

```
struct Final -> struct MI -> struct D1 -> struct Base -> struct Class
```

Writing something as `class Square: public Shape` indicates an [`is-a`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship, so Square *is-a* Shape. For your class chain, it also establishes the same realtionship between `Final` and `Class` albeit via a lot of intermediary parent lineage. Writing `public Class` is actually redundant in `struct Final : public MI, public Class`. In real-world analogy, it's akin to inidcating that the great-great-grandfather is the direct father, which unless we're discussing fantasy or something perverse, is not applicable. The compiler claims as much [here](https://godbolt.org/z/48eecfsY4) in the warning showing the ambiguity it's posed with and then fails to compile the code. There's a much more nuanced answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118412/inaccessible-direct-base-caused-by-multiple-inheritance). For your specific question, just removing `Class` from `Final` should be [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/b4TjhcEc5) for compiling.

P.S. Please do consider renaming `Class` to something else since this is C++ and well...`class` is a big thing. `class Class` would be very unreadable.